# Query about bounded variable simplex method

Tags: operations-research, simplex-method

Are bounded variable simplex and bounded variable primal simplex method same? If not where does these two differ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall seeing a bounded variable variant of the dual simplex method, so as far as I know the two phrases are interchangeable.